# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined when running ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My response keeps getting a return as undefined.

My **`index.php`** has an event handler that fires off the following code

```
$.post("getData.php", onNewPost());

function onNewPost (response){

  if (response.status == "OK") {
     console.log(response);
  }

};//end new post
```

and My **`getdata.php`** is as follows

```
 <?php 
 $data = array("status" => "OK");
```

Comment: the `post` line should be like this `$.post("getData.php", onNewPost);`

Comment: still returnes undefined

Comment: @dontay please update the code in your question. Also, how does `$data` in your PHP script become a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your index.php to

```
$.post("getData.php", onNewPost);

function onNewPost (response){
    // console.log(response);
    response_parse = JSON.parse(response);
    if (response_parse.status == "OK") {
        console.log(response);
    }

};//end new post
```

getdata.php

```
$data = array("status" => "OK");
die(json_encode($data));
```

Here, first create the array in your getdata.php and `json_encode` that data.
After that `JSON.parse` the returned data in your script, this will convert the data to JavaScript object. [See here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)